# Popup with disabled background using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to display the error/success messages from my try/catch blocks by using a popping up a div and disabling the background until an 'accept' or cancel button is clicked. I have found a method to accomplish this using javascript (below), and I know I can call it with a ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() in c#, however I believe I need to accomplish the same thing entirely in c#/asp.net in order to ease the process of including and populating asp controls within the div.

I've included the html/css/js below (credit to madan712 on GitHub).  Does anyone know how to accomplish the same thing using asp.net?

Am I entirely off-base with trying to accomplish this with asp.net and should be looking at another method?

Thanks

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Popup div with disabled background</TITLE>
    <style>
        .ontop {
            z-index: 999;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;             
            background-color: #cccccc;
            color: #aaaaaa;
            opacity: .4;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
        }
        #popup {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            color: #000000;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            /* To align popup window at the center of screen*/
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -100px;
            margin-left: -150px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pop(div) {
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
        }
        function hide(div) {
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
        }
        //To detect escape button
        document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
            evt = evt || window.event;
            if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
                hide('popDiv');
            }
        };
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <div id="popDiv" class="ontop">
        <table border="1" id="popup">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    This is can be used as a popup window
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Click Close OR escape button to close it
                    <a href="#" onClick="hide('popDiv')">Close</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <CENTER>
        <h3>
            Simple popup div with disabled background
        </h3>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" onClick="pop('popDiv')">Click here to open a popup div</a>
    </CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```